# Wand turns transparent background to black

Tags: python, grayscale, wand, magickwand

I am trying to grayscale with python using Wand, but when I do

```
from wand.image import Image
with Image(filename='image.png') as img:
    img.type = 'grayscale'
    img.save(filename='image_gray.png')
```

it turns the transparent background into black. If I use one with white background it works. What do I do wrong. And also as grayscaling is

```
Y = 0.2126 * RED + 0.7152 * GREEN + 0.0722 * BLUE
```

Where can I do that manually in Wand, say if I want to change the values a bit. I looked in the documentation and in various forums but I couldn't find any answer, only stuff for photoshop.

Thanks!

Comment: JPEG doesn't have transparency, so is it that you want the background to consistently be turned into white?

Comment: Right, sorry I posted the wrong code, I edited it. Does that mean I should convert every image to a jpg first and can't grayscale pngs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PNG image type set to grayscale removes transparent layer (see [PNG docs](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter08.html)). One option would be to enable the Alpha channel after setting grayscale.

```py
img.alpha = True
# or
img.background_color = Color('transparent')
```

Depending on which version you have, this might not work.

**Another Option**

Alter the color saturation with [Image.modulate](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.0/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.modulate).

```py
img.modulate(saturation=0.0)
```

**Another Option**

Alter the colorspace.

```py
img.colorspace = 'gray'
# or
img.colorspace = 'rec709luma'
# or
img.colorspace = 'rec601luma'
```

**Another Option**

If your version has `Image.fx`. The following would work

```py
with img.fx('lightness') as gray_copy:
   ....
```

Comment: ok thanks The second and third option works. The first one not, but I like it, what version do I need for it ? And the last option, what is image.fx? And lastly where did you find that the codes for the colorspace? I couldnt find it anywhere in the documentation

Comment: @PaulBernhardWagner still figuring that out. The C-API color structures of IM have altered with the upcoming IM7, and the next iteration of wan 0.4.1 will include some rewrites.

Comment: [Docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php) & [examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/index.html#fx) are a good start. Also checkout wand [development branch](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/blob/0.4-maintenance/wand/image.py#L1868) for near features.

Answer (score 1):

this doesnt answer your question about wand ... but you can do it easy enough with just pil ...

```
from PIL import Image
from math import ceil
import q
def CalcLuminosity(RED,GREEN,BLUE):
    return int(ceil(0.2126 * RED + 0.7152 * GREEN + 0.0722 * BLUE))

im = Image.open('bird.jpg')
# im.convert("L")  will apply the standard luminosity mapping

data = [CalcLuminosity(*im.getpixel((c,r))) for r in range(im.height) for c in range(im.width) ]

#now make our new image using our luminosity values
x = Image.new("L",(im.width,im.height))
image_px = x.load()
for c in range(im.width):
    for r in range(im.height):
        image_px[c,r] = data[r*im.width+c]

x.save("output.jpg")
```

or if you wanted to limit extremes based on a threshold

```
#now make our new image using our luminosity values
x = Image.new("L",(im.width,im.height))
image_px = x.load()
for c in range(im.width):
    for r in range(im.height):
        image_px[c,r] = 0 if data[r*im.width+c] < 120 else 255

x.save("output.jpg")
```

or if you wanted to filter a single color chanel

```
def CalcLuminosityBLUE(RED,GREEN,BLUE):
    return BLUE
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try that out, I like this one because you can edit the grayscale